# Make weighted calculations based on dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, weighted

I have to calculate the weighted scores of different players of a game. I have their individual scores in the first three columns, and their weights in the next three columns, which differ depending on the game (each row represents one game).

Can anyone help me with the calculation of the weighted scores in an efficient manner?

```
df <- data.frame(player1 = c(1,2,1), player2 = c(2,2,1), player3 = c(2,2,2), weightplayer1=c(0.7,0.8,0.7), weightplayer2 = c(0.6,0.1,0.6), weightplayer3=c(0.2,0.7,0.2))

#  player1 player2 player3 weightplayer1 weightplayer2 weightplayer3  
#       1       2       2      0.7           0.6            0.2
#       2       2       2      0.8           0.1            0.7
#       1       1       2      0.7           0.6            0.2
```

I need an output like this, where the weighted1scores column takes the sum of the weights
of the players that scored 1, and the weighted2scores column takes the sum of the weights
of the players who scored 2. I actually have a long list of possible scores, so in reality
this dataframe has a lot of columns (with up until weighted100scores etc.)
Hence, an efficient formula/loop would be great.

```
#  player1 player2 player3 weightplayer1 weightplayer2 weightplayer3  weighted1scores  weighted2scores
#       1       2       2      0.7           0.6            0.2              0.7              0.8  
#       2       2       2      0.8           0.1            0.7               0               1.6
#       1       1       2      0.7           0.6            0.2              1.3              0.2
```

Comment: It usually helps a lot if your table is normalized to 3NF to have one table of weights and another table of scores. Then you can join the tables by a common column e.g. player_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solutions so far don't reproduce your output, probably because you don't use "weights" the way we expect.

The following does it :

```r
df <- data.frame(player1 = c(1,2,1), player2 = c(2,2,1), player3 = c(2,2,2), weightplayer1=c(0.7,0.8,0.7), weightplayer2 = c(0.6,0.1,0.6), weightplayer3=c(0.2,0.7,0.2))

library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% mutate(game = row_number())
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = player1:weightplayer3,
    names_to = c(".value", "player_id"),
    names_pattern = "(.+)(\\d)") %>% 
  rename(score = player, weight = weightplayer, player = player_id) %>% 
  group_by(game, score_col = paste0("weighted",score,"score")) %>% 
  summarize(weightedscore = sum(weight)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = score_col, values_from = weightedscore, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  left_join(df, .) %>% 
  select(-game) %>% 
  as.data.frame() # just to print all columns
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'game'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> Joining, by = "game"
#>   player1 player2 player3 weightplayer1 weightplayer2 weightplayer3
#> 1       1       2       2           0.7           0.6           0.2
#> 2       2       2       2           0.8           0.1           0.7
#> 3       1       1       2           0.7           0.6           0.2
#>   weighted1score weighted2score
#> 1            0.7            0.8
#> 2            0.0            1.6
#> 3            1.3            0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

We first reshape to tidy data (one observation per row), where we should ideally stay until reporting, then we do our aggregated calculation, reshape it to untidy and stitch it back to the original data.frame .

Comment: Thanks  a lot!! THis was super helpful. do you know how I can incorporate a dynamic count, where if a player scores 0, their weight is excluded from the calculation?

Comment: You could replace these 0s with NA and use na.rm = TRUE in sum

Answer (score 2):

You can normalize your tables to 3NF and then join and aggregate:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(player1 = c(1, 2, 1), player2 = c(2, 2, 1), player3 = c(2, 2, 2), weightplayer1 = c(0.7, 0.8, 0.7), weightplayer2 = c(0.6, 0.1, 0.6), weightplayer3 = c(0.2, 0.7, 0.2))

scores <-
  df %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "game") %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("player")) %>%
  transmute(
    game,
    player_id = name %>% str_extract("[0-9]+$"),
    score = value
  )
scores
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   game  player_id score
#>   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 1     1             1
#> 2 1     2             2
#> 3 1     3             2
#> 4 2     1             2
#> 5 2     2             2
#> 6 2     3             2
#> 7 3     1             1
#> 8 3     2             1
#> 9 3     3             2

weights <-
  df %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "game") %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("weight")) %>%
  transmute(
    game,
    player_id = name %>% str_extract("[0-9]+$"),
    weight = value
  )
weights
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   game  player_id weight
#>   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 1     1            0.7
#> 2 1     2            0.6
#> 3 1     3            0.2
#> 4 2     1            0.8
#> 5 2     2            0.1
#> 6 2     3            0.7
#> 7 3     1            0.7
#> 8 3     2            0.6
#> 9 3     3            0.2

scores %>%
  inner_join(weights) %>%
  group_by(player_id, game) %>%
  summarise(weighted = sum(weight)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = player_id,
    values_from = weighted,
    names_prefix = "weighted"
  )
#> Joining, by = c("game", "player_id")
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'player_id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   game  weighted1 weighted2 weighted3
#>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 1           0.7       0.6       0.2
#> 2 2           0.8       0.1       0.7
#> 3 3           0.7       0.6       0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method:

```
df %>%
  mutate(game = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('player'), names_to = "Player", values_to = "Score") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('weightplayer'), names_to = "WPlayer", values_to = "Weight") %>%
  filter(parse_number(Player) == parse_number(WPlayer)) %>%
  select(-WPlayer) %>%
  mutate(
    WeightedScore = Score * Weight
  )
```

Which you could leave as is to return this tidy table

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
   game Player  Score Weight WeightedScore
  <int> <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1 player1     1    0.7           0.7
2     1 player2     2    0.6           1.2
3     1 player3     2    0.2           0.4
4     2 player1     2    0.8           1.6
5     2 player2     2    0.1           0.2
6     2 player3     2    0.7           1.4
7     3 player1     1    0.7           0.7
8     3 player2     1    0.6           0.6
9     3 player3     2    0.2           0.4
```

Or continue on with:

```
df %>%
  mutate(game = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('player'), names_to = "Player", values_to = "Score") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('weightplayer'), names_to = "WPlayer", values_to = "Weight") %>%
  filter(parse_number(Player) == parse_number(WPlayer)) %>%
  select(-WPlayer) %>%
  mutate(
    WeightedScore = Score * Weight
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Score, Weight, WeightedScore)) %>%
  mutate(name = paste(Player, name, sep = '_')) %>%
  pivot_wider(id = game)
```

To end at:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 10
   game player1_Score player1_Weight player1_WeightedScore player2_Score player2_Weight player2_WeightedScore player3_Score player3_Weight player3_WeightedScore
  <int>         <dbl>          <dbl>                 <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>                 <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>                 <dbl>
1     1             1            0.7                   0.7             2            0.6                   1.2             2            0.2                   0.4
2     2             2            0.8                   1.6             2            0.1                   0.2             2            0.7                   1.4
3     3             1            0.7                   0.7             1            0.6                   0.6             2            0.2                   0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach which may be a bit more concise:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(output = pmap(., ~ {x <- c(...)[startsWith(names(df), "player")]
  y <- c(...)[startsWith(names(df), "weight")]
  as_tibble(cbind(sum(y[x == 1]), sum(y[x == 2])))})) %>%
  unnest_wider(output) %>%
  rename_with(~ gsub("V(\\d+)", "Weighted\\1scores", .), starts_with("V"))

# A tibble: 3 x 8
  player1 player2 player3 weightplayer1 weightplayer2 weightplayer3 Weighted1scores
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>
1       1       2       2           0.7           0.6           0.2             0.7
2       2       2       2           0.8           0.1           0.7             0  
3       1       1       2           0.7           0.6           0.2             1.3
# ... with 1 more variable: Weighted2scores <dbl>
```